# Alexa lambda_handler not creating event session

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am having a problem getting my python lambda function to work.  I get an invalid key for the event array that should be created when the skill is invoked.  The error I get is:

```
{
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
            163,
            "lambda_handler",
            "app_id = event['session']['application']['applicationId']"
            ]
    ],
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "errorMessage": "'session'"
}
```

and here is my code

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):


"""Lambda function entrypoint."""
# print("event.session.application.applicationId={}".format(
#       event['session']['application']['applicationId']))

# Prevent unwanted access to this Lambda function.
app_id = event['session']['application']['applicationId']
if app_id != "amzn1.ask.skill.yyyyyyyy-xxx":
    raise ValueError("Invalid Application ID: {}".format(app_id))

request = event['request']

if event['session']['new']:
    on_session_started(
        {'requestId': request['requestId']}, event['session'])

func_map = {
    "LaunchRequest": on_launch,
    "IntentRequest": on_intent,
    "SessionEndedRequest": on_session_ended,
}

return func_map[request['type']](event['request'], event['session'])
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem was I had configured the wrong test in the Lambda Function dashboard.  When I changed it to an Alexa Start Session, the event object got created.  :)

Answer (score 1):

We just started a project [bstpy](https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy) to expose a Python lambda as an http service. You may find it useful for testing. You can throw json payloads at it with curl or postman. If you try it with other [Bespoken Tools](https://github.com/bespoken/bst) you can a have very nice development environment